# Events in dynamic checkbox array from database

Tags: jquery, arrays, dynamic, checkbox, bind

Hi I have a problem trying to bind events in a checkboxes array looks as if bind method is not working, I put an alert to probe event but seems nothing happened

Here is my jquery code

```
$('input[name="id_especieganado[]"]').each(function(e){
    //$('[name="id_especieganado[]"]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var id_jurisdiccion = new Array();
        var jurisdicciones = "";
        //id_jurisdiccion = $("#id_jurisdiccion[]");
        var i = 0;
        $(this).bind('click',function(){
        //$('input[name="id_especieganado[]"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                alert($(this).val());
                id_jurisdiccion.push($(this).val());
                jurisdicciones += "id_jurisdiccion[]="+$(this).val()+"&";
                $("#buscarrfc").val("Hola");
            }
        })
        //if($("#id_jurisdiccion[]").attr("checked")==true)
            //alert($("input[name='id_jurisdiccion[]']").val());
        $.ajax({
            url:"funciones_jquery2.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: jurisdicciones,
            success: function(datos){
                $("#listamunicipios").html(datos);
                //alert(datos);
            }
        })
            //})
    });
```

And the dynamic array generated from database comes from next method in class

```
private function especies_ganado()
    {
        $database = $this->conexion_db();
        $resultado = pg_query($database, "SELECT *FROM especies_ganado;");
        echo "<tr><td>";
        while($row = pg_fetch_array($resultado))
        {
            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"id_especieganado[]\" id=\"id_especieganado[]\" value=\"$row[id_especieganado]\"> $row[especie_ganado]<BR>";
        }
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
```

This is a private method wich is used from another public method to populate the list, the checkboxes are printed but events are not been binded.
The checkboxes are printed depending on the select control in next jquery code.

```
$("#id_cedulaverificacion").change(function(){
        var id_cedulaverificacion = $("#id_cedulaverificacion").val();
        var id_tipovisita = $("#id_tipovisita").val();
        //alert(id_cedulaverificacion);
        $.ajax({
            url: "funciones_jquery.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "id_cedulaverificacion="+id_cedulaverificacion+"&id_tipovisita="+id_tipovisita,
            success: function(datos){
                $("#cedulas").html(datos);
            }
        });
    });
```

Any help I would really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You don't need each loop for a click event; use `.on()` for dynamically added element.

```
 $(document).on('click','input[name="id_especieganado[]"]',function(){
    
   var jurisdicciones = $('input[name="id_especieganado[]"]:checked').map(function(){
       return this.value;
    }).get().join(',');
    alert(jurisdicciones); //this will have comma seperated checked values
    if(jurisdicciones !=""){ //check if not empty then call ajax
      $.ajax({
        url:"funciones_jquery2.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {data:jurisdicciones}, //comma seperated values.
        success: function(datos){
            $("#listamunicipios").html(datos);
            //alert(datos);
        }
      })
    }
        
});
```

With this the checked values is posted as `data` to server so you can explode it with `,` and get corresponding values. I am using if just in case if the checked value is empty then no need to call ajax. You can modify it as you need.